# mysql counts with group by to show all types per country include where no record is present as 0

Tags: mysql, group-by, count

I have the following mysql query and attempting to do group by country and type, however for all countries not all types are available but would still like to see all types for every country populated with 0.

```
select distinct
t1.Country,
t2.sectype,
count(t1.secid) AS SecID
from test.t2
left outer join test.t1 on test.t2.sectype= test.t1.sectype
group by t1.Country, t2.sectype;
```

t1 has country, sectype and secid fields and have created another table t2 which has all sectype's possible.

I get the following output:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/VAdyj.png

As you can see Germany only has 3 sectype's attached to that country but would like to see all sectype's like Canada - to be like the following output:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZC73H.png

Is this possible to do? Thanks

Comment: Do you hold all countries and all types somewhere?

Comment: I have all types in t2 but also have all countries somewhere else, but all countries are also present within t1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider a cross join of your distinct country and sectype tables. Then left join this all possible pairings to your actual data table. Finally, use a `SUM` condition over `COUNT`. Below uses table names that should be updated to your actual tables:

```
select cj.Country,
       cj.sectype,
       sum(d.secid IS NOT NULL) AS Count_SecID    
from 
    (select n.country, s.sectype
     from sectypes_table s
     cross join countries_table n) cj
left outer join actual_data d
    on d.sectype = cj.sectype AND d.country = cj.country    
group by cj.Country, 
         cj.sectype;
```

To avoid the cross join should you have many distinct values, create such a table beforehand and replace subquery with this new table:

```
create table country_sectypes as (
   select n.country, s.sectype
   from sectypes_table s
   cross join countries_table n
);

select cs.Country,
       cs.sectype,
       sum(d.secid IS NOT NULL) AS Count_SecID    
from country_sectypes cs
left outer join actual_data d
    on d.sectype = cs.sectype AND d.country = cs.country    
group by cs.Country, 
         cs.sectype;
```

[Rextester Demo](https://rextester.com/EBRM22164) *(using actual_data for distinct country and sectype)*